# Copy the HTML table to clipboard in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, html-table

I have an HTML table in my react project. I want to copy the table to clipboard.

```
<table id="sample">
 <thead>
  <th>Amount</th>
  <th>Charges</th>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
   <tr>{item.Amount}</tr>
   <tr>{item.Charges}</tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the table structure . I haven't included any react code.

I referred this sample code https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-copy-element?file=index.js . But it's not in react.

Using react code how can I copy the table to clipboard?

Answer (score 9):

might be too late to answer this, but here's how I did it.

I had  element rendered in my component's render function.

```
render(){
    return(
        <table id="table">
         .... your table content
        </table>
    )
}
```

and simply build a copy function by referring to the sample code shared above.

```
copyTable = () => {
const elTable = document.querySelector('table');

let range, sel;

// Ensure that range and selection are supported by the browsers
if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {

  range = document.createRange();
  sel = window.getSelection();
  // unselect any element in the page
  sel.removeAllRanges();

  try {
    range.selectNodeContents(elTable);
    sel.addRange(range);
  } catch (e) {
    range.selectNode(elTable);
    sel.addRange(range);
  }

  document.execCommand('copy');
}

sel.removeAllRanges();

console.log('Element Copied! Paste it in a file')
```

}

then, call this function by building an element like this

```
<h1 onClick={()=>{this.copyTable()}}>Copy to table</h1>
```