# Replace certain tag with another when copying to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to copy a table from the webpage to either Word document or email, but everything in `<textarea>` just cannot display correctly after pasting.

I found a couple ways to replace the `<textarea>` tag with `<span>`, but because I don't want to affect the editability of the original table, I have to manipulate the clone of the table Element.
The question is, how do I send this cloned & modified table element to the clipboard without affecting the actual DOM?

copy method learned from [Copy the HTML table to clipboard in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966672/copy-the-html-table-to-clipboard-in-reactjs)

```js
copyTable = () =>{
    const elTable = document.getElementById('my_table').cloneNode(true);
    var textareas = elTable.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
    for(let txtarea of textareas){
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      span.innerText = txtarea.defaultValue;
      txtarea.parentNode.appendChild(span);
      txtarea.parentNode.removeChild(txtarea);
    }
    
    var range, sel;
    if(document.createRange && window.getSelection){
      range = document.createRange();
      sel = window.getSelection();
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      
      try{
        range.selectNodeContents(elTable);
        console.log("range:",range);
        sel.addRange(range);
      }catch(e){
        range.selectNode(elTable);
        sel.addRange(range);
      }
      
      document.execCommand('copy');
    }
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    
    console.log("copied");
  }
```

If I don't make `elTable` a clone, then the swap works and so does the copy, but it also changes the `<textarea>` to `<span>` on the actual DOM, which is something I don't want.
If I use `document.getElementById('my_table').cloneNode(true);`, then the copy doesn't work at all for some reason..

Is there a way to send my cloned/modified table element to the clipboard?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there is nothing selected on the cloned node, only on the original.

To do this you need to:

- Clone the table
- Modify the original
- Write modified original to clipboard
- Replace original with clone

Comment: Thanks Dan! But I want to avoid modifying the original, so that the table cells with `<textarea>` can still be modified on the webpage.(because I need to use onInput within textarea). But I can't figure out how to get the modified clone written to clipboard